# Replacing contents of Jframe with new items returns blank Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have  a start up window that creates a jframe with a drop down box, two text boxes and an OK button.  After choosing the drop down menu item and then typing in the two text boxes, another function is called that will replace the contents of the JFrame with other content.

One of the drop down choices is to deposit:

```
 public void deposit(String customerID, String customerPIN) {
    Customer customer = validate_info(customerID, customerPIN);
    if (!found){
        if (pin == null) {
            jf.notInDatabase();
        } else {
            jf.invalidAccount(); // if the customer has not been found but the pin has been set that means the pin was invalid
        }
    } else {
        if (customer != null) {
            String result = customer.returnInfo();
            jf.depositScreen(result);
```

After looking around on SO for guidance, this is what I have so far:

```
public void depositScreen(String phrase) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();

    JLabel customerInfo = new JLabel(phrase);
    customerInfo.setFont(new Font("Futura", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    getContentPane().add(customerInfo);

    JTextField depositAmount = new JTextField("Please enter the amount you would like to deposit in 00.00 format");
    depositAmount.setFont(new Font("Futura", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    getContentPane().add(depositAmount);

    repaint();
    validate();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

So far it's turning up a blank gray box without the labels in it.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You don't have to setVisible again. validate should come before repaint. You should invalidate your contentpane. Also what layout does your content pane have?

Comment: Use `revalidate` or `invalidate` followed by `validate` and `repaint` should be called last.  No need to use `setVisible`.  A better solution might be to just use a `CardLayout`

Comment: Check the layout which you are using. Also, try with setting a `JPanel` as `contentPane` first and add your components to this panel. This would help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example doing what you want. Notice the order of the validates and invalidates.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class SwingSwap{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->buildGui());
    }
    public static void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("swapping");
        final JButton a = new JButton("->B");
        final JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("A");

        final JButton b = new JButton("->A");
        final JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("B");

        a.addActionListener(evt->{
            EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
                Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
                cont.removeAll();
                cont.add(b);
                cont.add(bLabel);
                cont.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
                frame.repaint();
            });
         });

        b.addActionListener(evt->{
            EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
                Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
                cont.removeAll();
                cont.add(a);
                cont.add(aLabel);
                cont.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
                frame.repaint();
            });
        } );

        Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cont, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        cont.add(a);
        cont.add(aLabel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work; showing an empty gray box.  If it helps any, I'm using grid layout and this function is not attached to an ActionListener.

Comment: @Drivebyluna did you compile the example I provided?

Comment: Yes it compiles.  I'll add an edit to show how my repainting is being called.

Comment: @Drivebyluna Does this example switch components correctly when the buttons are clicked? You still haven't changed the invalidate/validate/repaint in your question.

Comment: It does, only if I call your method from the main class.  If I put it in the frame class, which is where I want all of this to happen, it gives me this:  http://imgur.com/dEQoKFu which has not removed any of the previous items but just added more on top of it.

Anyways, I got around this repainting business this morning by just destroying and recreating a frame within the deposit function of my atm class.